# How to add a new custom field in pos print receipt in odoo 11

Tags: jquery, xml, odoo-11

I want to add my custom field in pos print receipt in odoo 11 and 
this is my js code:

```
var module = require('point_of_sale.models');
var models = module.PosModel.prototype.models;
for(var i=0; i<models.length; i++){
    var model=models[i];
    if(model.model === 'res.partner'){
         model.fields.push('custom_field1');
    }

}
```

and XML Code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <templates id="point_of_sale.template" xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="PosTicket" t-extend="PosTicket">
       <t t-jquery=".receipt-user"  t-operation="after">
          <t t-if="order.get_client().name">
            <t t-esc="order.get_client().name"/> </t>
            <t t-if="order.get_client().custom_field">
            <t t-esc="order.get_client().custom_field"/> </t>
    </t>  
</t> </templates>
```

The value gets printed in debug mode and not in normal mode.

Comment: Please share the answer if you get it